# TFS 2015 - required fields between states

Tags: xml, tfs, tfs-2015

In the Product Backlog Item XML file, within TRANSITION for "Approved" to "Ready", I have set a number of fields set as REQUIRED.  I've set all transitions accordingly.  For further measure, I've set these fields as REQUIRED within the STATE "Ready", including all states.

The rules work fine, first time.  Once I change the state backwards, or forward to the "happy path", I'm able to remove the values from most of the fields, except "Effort", before saving.  Why is the "Effort" field working fine, but not the others?

Help please.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the XML of the WITD?

Comment: Which rule are you actually want to use "State-specific" for a certain state or  "Transition-specific"  that is undergoing a certain transition? Suggest you add related XML file in your question?